# Wait until action finished by take doesn't work (redux saga)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am using redux-saga & redux to handle asynchronous process at react, but put&take doesn't work. Any idea why?

In saga's generator function, I dispatch the action `test-action` by `put`.
Then I want to wait until the action is completed, so I try to do it by `take`, but `take` is not called.

In redux-devtool, I can find `test-action` is surely dispatched.

```
function* firstActionSaga(){
  // dispatch secondAction
  yield put(secondAction())

  // If secondAction finished, the below line should be called.
  yield take("SECOND_ACTION")

  console.log("second action finished.")
}

function* rootSaga() {
 yield all([

   // Wait for firstAction, and start firstActionSaga
   yield takeEvery(FIRST_ACTION, firstActionSaga)
])
}
```

## Expected

1. Wait for firstAction, and start firstActionSaga
2. Dispatch secondAction by `put`
3. Wait until secondAction, and do something.

## Actual

1. Wait for firstAction, and start firstActionSaga
2. Dispatch secondAction by `put`
3. `take` is not fired

Comment: kindly share the file where 'secondAction' is defined and may be you need 'saga dev' tool to watch 'test-action'.

Comment: I didn't know saga-dev-tool, thanks, I'll try later

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I can do what I wanna do by using 'putResolve'.